# How can I use indexof and substring and string.format to add random numbers/text in specific place in text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my original code and it's working fine but the text content is already in the editor in a Text UI and therefore it's also in the variable textField.
So I don't want to type the text over again also inside the code. For example the word toBeSearched is "almost" so using the string format it will generate new random number each time I press on space between the words: "almost" and  "hours".

But since the text is already in the textField variable I want to parse the place I want to add the random numbers automatic using indexof and substring.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CustomText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string toBeSearched;
    public Text textField;

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateRandomHour();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GenerateRandomHour();
        }
    }

    private void GenerateRandomHour()
    {
        string numberName = Random.Range(1, 10).ToString();
        textField.text = string.Format("Hello my friend, It's about time to wakeup. You were sleeping for almost {0} hours. My name is NAVI and i'm your navigation helper in the game.", numberName);
    }
}
```

This is the code with the indexof and substring I tried to use but it#s not working good.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CustomText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string toBeSearched;
    public Text textField;

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateRandomHour();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GenerateRandomHour();
        }
    }

    private void GenerateRandomHour()
    {
        string result = null;
        string result1 = null;
        int ix = textField.text.IndexOf(toBeSearched);

        if (ix != -1)
        {
            result = textField.text.Substring(0, ix + toBeSearched.Length);
            result1 = textField.text.Substring(ix + toBeSearched.Length, textField.text.Length - (ix + toBeSearched.Length));
        }

        result1 = result1.TrimStart();

        string numberName = Random.Range(1, 10).ToString();
        textField.text = string.Format(result + " {0} " + result1, numberName);
    }
}
```

Again the word toBeSearched is "almost" and I used a breakpoint and result contain the text until almost: "Hello my friend, It's about time to wakeup. You were sleeping for almost" and the variable result1 contain the rest of the text: "hours. My name is NAVI and i'm your navigation helper in the game."

But now when I'm pressing the space key it's inserting each time a new random number but it's not replacing the whole text like in the original code above.
So the result is many numbers in the text.

Not sure why it's not working like the original code.

Comment: What about store the original value of the text field on Start like **defaultValue = textField.text** and use **textField.text = string.Format(defaultValue, numberName);**?

Comment: @NathaliaSoragge And how do I parse and format the text so the random numbers will be in the right place ?

Comment: Just place the {0} in the text field in the position you want the number to be. I'm going to add this in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because you're changing the value of `textField.text`, so when you repeat the process the substrings are generated with this new value, including the number. You shouldn't give up your first solution, it's much cleaner. Store the original value of the text field on Start:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CustomText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string toBeSearched;
    public Text textField;
    private string defaultValue;

    private void Start()
    {
        defaultValue = textField.text;
        GenerateRandomHour();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GenerateRandomHour();
        }
    }

    private void GenerateRandomHour()
    {
        string numberName = Random.Range(1, 10).ToString();
        textField.text = string.Format(defaultValue, numberName);
    }
}
```

Add the {0} directly to your text field value in the inspector:

**Hello my friend, It's about time to wakeup. You were sleeping for almost {0} hours. My name is NAVI and i'm your navigation helper in the game.**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you are adding a number in a specified spot, so every time you press space, it is using the existing text as the template and thus the old number stays,along with adding a new one.

Instead, you want to search between the two words "almost" and "hours" so you can replace whatevers between them. You can do this the by adding another indexOf search, but itll be easier using regex.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(textField.text, "(? <=almost).+?(?=hours)" , numberName);
textField.text = result;
```

Although your first solution looks cleaner, and if you want to keep the text in the inspector, Nathalia's answer would work